# I can't inject my IUnitOfWork class into my ApartmentManager class

Tags: entity-framework, dependency-injection, entity-framework-core, autofac, unit-of-work

I'm building an apartment dues management system. Below are my related classes. If I inject my `IUnitOfWork` class in my `ApartmentManager` class and pass it in ctor it gives the following error.

mistake:

> Autofac.Core.DependencyResolutionException: An exception was thrown while activating Business.Concrete.ApartmentManager -> DataAccess.Concrete.UnitOfWork.UnitOfWork.

> ---> Autofac.Core.DependencyResolutionException: None of the constructors found on type 'DataAccess.Concrete.UnitOfWork.UnitOfWork' can be invoked with the available services and parameters:

> Cannot resolve parameter 'DataAccess.Concrete.EntityFramework.Context.ApartmentDuesManagementContext context' of constructor 'Void .ctor(DataAccess.Concrete.EntityFramework.Context.ApartmentDuesManagementContext)'.
> Classes:

```cs
public class AutofacBusinessModule : Module
{
    protected override void Load(ContainerBuilder builder)
    {
        builder.RegisterType<UnitOfWork>().As<IUnitOfWork>()
            .InstancePerLifetimeScope();
        builder.RegisterType<EfApartmentDal>().As<IApartmentDal>()
            .InstancePerLifetimeScope();
        builder.RegisterType<ApartmentManager>()
            .As<IApartmentService>()
            .InstancePerLifetimeScope();
    }
}
```

```
public interface IUnitOfWork
    {
        Task CommitAsync();
        void Commit();
        //Task<int> SaveChangesAsync();
        //Task BeginTransactionAsync();
        //Task CommitTransactionAsync();
        //Task RollbackTransactionAsync();

        //public interface IEntityRepository<T> where T : class, IEntity, new()
        //{
        //    Task AddRangeAsync(IEnumerable<T> entities);
        //}

        //public interface IApartmentRepository : IEntityRepository<Apartment> { }
    }
```

```
 public class UnitOfWork : IUnitOfWork
    {
        private readonly ApartmentDuesManagementContext _context;
        //private IDbContextTransaction _transaction;
        public UnitOfWork(ApartmentDuesManagementContext context)
        {
            _context = context;
        }
        public void Commit()
        {
            _context.SaveChanges();
        }

        public async Task CommitAsync()
        {
            await _context.SaveChangesAsync();
        }
}
```

```
public class EfApartmentDal : EfEntityRepositoryBase<Apartment, ApartmentDuesManagementContext>, IApartmentDal
    {
       
    }
```

```
public interface IApartmentDal : IEntityRepository<Apartment>
    {
        
    }
```

```
public interface IApartmentService
    {
        IDataResult<List<Apartment>> GetList();
        Task<IDataResult<Task<IEnumerable<Apartment>>>> AddRangeAsync<TEntity>(IEnumerable<Apartment> apartments);
    }
```

```
public class ApartmentManager : IApartmentService
    {
        private readonly IApartmentDal _apartmentDal;
        private readonly IUnitOfWork _unitOfWork;
        public ApartmentManager(IApartmentDal apartmentDal, IUnitOfWork unitOfWork)
        {
            _apartmentDal = apartmentDal;
            _unitOfWork = unitOfWork;
        }

        public IDataResult<List<Apartment>> GetList()
        {
            return new SuccessDataResult<List<Apartment>>(_apartmentDal.GetList(), "Apartmanlar basarili bir sekilde listelendi.");
        }

        public async Task<IDataResult<Task<IEnumerable<Apartment>>>> AddRangeAsync<TEntity>(IEnumerable<Apartment> apartments)
        {
            await _apartmentDal.AddRangeAsync(apartments);
            await _unitOfWork.CommitAsync();
            return new SuccessDataResult<Task<IEnumerable<Apartment>>>(Task.FromResult(apartments), "Kayıt ekleme başarılı");
        }
    }
```

If I do not add the constructor in the manager class, the error disappears. but if I do it this way, I can't use it in the manager class, right? I would be very happy if anyone with a solution can help.

When I wanted to add 100 records in the Manager class, I was hoping that this would be done with the unit of work design pattern in a single operation to the database. but when I added this to my ApartmentManager class's constructor I got an error.

Comment: [Have you read the docs?](https://autofac.readthedocs.io/en/latest/troubleshooting/exceptions/no-found-constructors-can-be-invoked.html)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you look at the error message, it should tell you what is wrong. The first line is:

> Autofac.Core.DependencyResolutionException: An exception was thrown while activating Business.Concrete.ApartmentManager -> DataAccess.Concrete.UnitOfWork.UnitOfWork.

This means that Autofac tries to create an instance of `Business.Concrete.ApartmentManager`. It sees that it needs to create an instance of `DataAccess.Concrete.UnitOfWork.UnitOfWork` first. So it attempts to instantiate one.

But in order to instantiate it, it sees it needs to have an instance of `DataAccess.Concrete.EntityFramework.Context.ApartmentDuesManagementContext`, but it has no idea what that is or how to instantiate it.

That is what the rest of the error message means:

> ---> Autofac.Core.DependencyResolutionException: None of the constructors found on type 'DataAccess.Concrete.UnitOfWork.UnitOfWork' can be invoked with the available services and parameters:
>
> Cannot resolve parameter 'DataAccess.Concrete.EntityFramework.Context.ApartmentDuesManagementContext context' of constructor 'Void .ctor(DataAccess.Concrete.EntityFramework.Context.ApartmentDuesManagementContext)'.

So to solve it, you need to let Autofac know about `DataAccess.Concrete.EntityFramework.Context.ApartmentDuesManagementContext`. If you register this class when building the container, then Autofac can instantiate it:

```cs
public class AutofacBusinessModule : Module
{
    protected override void Load(ContainerBuilder builder)
    {
        builder.RegisterType<UnitOfWork>().As<IUnitOfWork>()
            .InstancePerLifetimeScope();
        builder.RegisterType<EfApartmentDal>().As<IApartmentDal>()
            .InstancePerLifetimeScope();
        builder.RegisterType<ApartmentManager>()
            .As<IApartmentService>()
            .InstancePerLifetimeScope();

        // Add this line
        builder
            .RegisterType<ApartmentDuesManagementContext>()
            .InstancePerLifetimeScope();
    }
}
```